# Angular Facebook post embedding. Where to put <script src="" nonce="">

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to embedd Facebook Posts on my Angular webpage. However Facebook is giving me as SDK following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

`<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous"` `src="https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v17.0&appId=828104822280632&autoLogAppEvents=1" nonce="a29QEhIu"></script>`

My question is, since I'd like to put the src in the Angular JSON file, where do I have to put the Nonce to make the SDK work?

I am just getting into Angular.

I tried to put the code inside my body, this is working, but however it interferes with the Instagram SDK.